# Set row numbers without group field

Tags: sql-server

Good day! I've such table set as:

[image]

How may I get each five RateValue from this table? 15270, 15420, 15360, etc... ? May anybody help me? I wanna do it just in one query without cycles and temp table or declaring new values.

Comment: can you please elaborate your question more clearly ??

Comment: You mean every fifth? Something like number % 5 = 1? Sounds quite a strange requirement...

Comment: I just need to select Date, RateValue for each five NUMBERS. 1,5,10,15, 20, 25...

Comment: So you need to do what @JamesZ said. WHERE NUMBER % 5 = 0

Comment: You should reword your title. It doesn't seem to be related to your actual question. For example: "Select every 5th value from table". Always keep in my mind that questions on stackoverflow are also supposed to help future readers.

Comment: I'll do it later. I have a lot of work now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can examine the remainder of division NUMBER by `5`:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE NUMBER % 5 = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE NUMBER % 5 = 0
```